# How to run following ruby project?

Tags: ruby, parsing, machine-learning

I want to run following ruby project in my local vs code editor in Windows 10.
https://github.com/inukshuk/anystyle
Can somebody please please help?

I don't know how to run it in local.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Answer (score 0):

First off, this project seems to be made for Linux, but alright!

Here are the steps I would recommand:
1 - Follow this tutorial https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-rubygems-in-windows/
2 - Run the following command on PowerShell using Administrator Mode

```bash
gem install anystyle
```

3 - Follow the rest of the tutorial on the rest of the github page you gave

Also, here is a small advice:
Give more details to where you are stuck. I assumed you have not tried installing Ruby, but I may be wrong!

Hope to have helped you

Answer (score 0):

You can clone this project into your local .
run command git clone (ssh link)
ssh-in code button you can copy ssh .
then run code . to open vs code

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).